# JavaFX resource handling: Load HTML files in WebView

Tags: java, javafx, webview, resources

I want to load an HTMLfile in the `WebView` of my JavaFX application. The file is located in my project directory, inside `webviewsample` package.

I've used the following code :

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.setTitle("WebView test");             

    WebView  browser = new WebView();
    WebEngine engine = browser.getEngine();
    String url = WebViewSample.class.getResource("/map.html").toExternalForm();
    engine.load(url);

    StackPane sp = new StackPane();
    sp.getChildren().add(browser);

    Scene root = new Scene(sp);

    primaryStage.setScene(root);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

But it throws an exception saying :

> Exception in Application start method
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You get this exception because your `url` variable is null on this line:

```
String url = WebViewSample.class.getResource("/map.html").toExternalForm();
```

---

You have several options with `getResource()`:

If the **resource is the same directory as the class**, then you can use

```
String url = WebViewSample.class.getResource("map.html").toExternalForm();
```

Using **beginning slash("/") means relative path to the project root.**:

In your particular case, if the resource is stored in the `webviewsample` package, you can get the resource as:

```
String url = WebViewSample.class.getResource("/webviewsample/map.html").toExternalForm();
```

Using a **beginning dot-slash("./") means relative path to path of the class**:

Imagine that you rclass is stored in package `webviewsample`, and your resource (`map.html`) is stored in a subdirectory `res`. You can use this command to get the URL:

```
String url = WebViewSample.class.getResource("./res/map.html").toExternalForm();
```

Based on this, if your resource is in the same directory with your class, then:

```
String url = WebViewSample.class.getResource("map.html").toExternalForm();
```

and

```
String url = WebViewSample.class.getResource("./map.html").toExternalForm();
```

are equivalent.

For further reading you can check [the documentation of `getResource()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Very nice answer !