# JavaFX - Resource paths and loading an image

Tags: image, javafx, path, directory, resources

My image doesn't want to be loaded, I don't know if it's the path, image format or error in the code. I have tried to detect what the problem is by different ways.

Here is the error code.

[image]

My workspace is located at

[image: https://s32.postimg.org/reakyw3qt/image.png]

This folder contains two additional folders, "bin" and "src". I have tried relocating my image to different subfolders just to be sure.

[image]

But still won't work, unfortunately. After having read the questions here on the site, there was a suggestion to check the path with these two short codes.

[image]

(tried also with texAccount.png)

The first command was successful, giving me the following line.

[image]

And then I became confused. It wants to load files from the "bin" subfolder, however my Scanner opens, reads, writes all the files into the root folder. I do not have my text files in the "bin" subfolder but the root folder and works perfectly. Maybe it just loads from the very first folder in my root folder? I created a subfolder named "asd" just to check it: No, I was wrong. The program definitely wants to load my image from the "bin" folder, giving me the same message as above.

I spammed all the folders with my picture. Okay, so my image is in the right folder after all. I thought I would check my code rather.

[image]

I tried to change the "texAccount.png" in code to just "texAccount", still would not load. Then I renamed my actual image file to "texAccount" and "texAccount.png", however I combined the names it showed no progress.
My image is only 20x20 in size, but contains alpha channel. As I am a beginner, I do not know, maybe alpha images must be dealt in some other ways, so to be sure I deleted my alpha channels and made a fully black picture, basically a 20x20 black box, no success.

I have tried converting my file to .jpg and three other formats.
I have imported all the required classes and packs needed for working with images.

Thank you very much!
( I posted all my codes and quotes as pictures )

Comment: Please do not post the code and error messages as images; post it as text and [format](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) it.

Comment: You could take a look on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359583/javafx-how-to-load-a-local-html-file-from-project-directory-in-webview/37364847#37364847) to figure out how could you load your image.

Comment: Thank you very much DVarga, this really helped me to figure out paths and my image is loaded now.
( Sorry for the codes as pictures, the page said I had problems with formatting, next time I promise I'm going to fix that too, I apologize )
Have a great day!

Comment: If this is solved, please add an answer below, rather than amending [solved] to the title - we prefer not to do that here. Thanks!

Comment: Also, James is quite right that we _require_ textual information to be provided as text, and if you receive a request to fix it up, please do even if the issue is solved. Ideally, we want to maintain questions here, so they are useful for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

```
Image image = new Image("texAccount.png");
```

Do not need to do other steps!