# Compiled .jar doesn't load a WebView content JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-webview

I saw similar problems but any of the solutions doesn't work in my issue. I've got a [project structre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGIjg.png) like this. I try to load a html file *map.html* to the WebView object by this code:

```
 try {
        String url = getClass().getResource("/html/map.html").toExternalForm();
        webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                setFunctionHandlerInHTML(webEngine, "app", this);
                borderPane.setDisable(false);
            }
        });
        webEngine.load(url);
```

I don't understand where the problem is couse i try to fallow instructions included in this post [JavaFX resource handling: Load HTML files in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359583/javafx-resource-handling-load-html-files-in-webview/37364847#37364847) but is still doesn't work.

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: List the contents of your .jar file.  Is there an `html/map.html` entry in it?

Comment: I used a WinRAR to list it and I've got a directory html and it has map.html...

Comment: When you say it “still doesn't work” what does that mean?  Are you getting an exception?  Is the WebView blank?

Comment: The WebView is blank (White).